# What's the farthest away from us a photon could theoretically reach?

Tags: cosmology, photons, speed-of-light, universe, space-expansion

Assuming the expansion of the universe will be dominated by dark matter, is there a limit to how far a photon could travel in terms of co-moving distance, as the Universe will be expanding faster than the speed of light.

Comment: The expansion of the universe is currently dominated by dark energy, not dark matter, and there is no compelling reason to think this will change.